# Numbered every row in a file based on the string found in one column in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, awk

I would like to numbered a tab file depends on the string within third column. So, if third column is like "X" the numbered is taking account a set of columns and if is like "Y" is numbered taking account other set of columns and so on. In this case I'm try to do this by the script below introducing if conditions by different ways but does not works correctly. It would be possible to do through the script below? or is there other more simple ways to do it in UNIX environment? Thanks in advance.

The input

```
rs868289783      355364  frameshift_variant      *       1004    S       del=1   dbSNP
rs868289783      355364  frameshift_variant      *       1004    S       del=1   dbSNP
                 180595  chemical-modification   R       18     D-R              PMD
rs747393379      264033  deletion_inframe                108             del=12  dbSNP
                 296037  inframe_deletion     NQMTGQISM  1405            del=9   ExAC
                 296037  inframe_deletion     NQMTGQISM  348             del=9   ExAC
```

The output would be

```
1    rs868289783      355364  frameshift_variant      *       1004    S       del=1   dbSNP
1    rs868289783      355364  frameshift_variant      *       1004    S       del=1   dbSNP
2                     180595  chemical-modification   R       18     D-R              PMD
3    rs747393379      264033  deletion_inframe                108             del=12  dbSNP
4                     296037  inframe_deletion     NQMTGQISM  1405            del=9   ExAC
4                     296037  inframe_deletion     NQMTGQISM  348             del=9   ExAC
```

The script I have used is something like

```
awk 'function intern(sym) {{ if (sym in table && $3 ~/frameshift_variant/)
                          return table[sym]
                        return table[sym] = ++counter}
 { print intern($2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6), $0 };
                         else if (sym in table && $3 ~/inframe_deletion/)
                          return table[sym]
                        return table[sym] = ++counter}
 { print intern($2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$7), $0 };
                         else if (sym in table && $3 ~/chemical-modification/)
                          return table[sym]
                        return table[sym] = ++counter}
 { print intern($2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6), $0 };
                         else if (sym in table && $3 ~/deletion_inframe/)
                          return table[sym]
                        return table[sym] = ++counter}
 { print intern($2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6), $0 }}' "input" > "output"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work correctly"?

Comment: Is the file always grouped by column 3? Will you see, for example, "frameshift_variant" show up elsewhere in the file?

Comment: I don't think your code would pass an `awkcheck` (if there was such a thing). I don't see that the opening `{` of your function def is ever closed, among other things. AND you never call the function in your code. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks all. Does not work correctly because in fact numbered but not following that I would like to do explained above. Maybe I write wrong the code here but I have run the code with the right syntax. In fact the file is sorted by 3rd column since I want to numbered based on this column. However, depends on the contents in 3rd column the numbered will be taking account one set of columns or another. For this reason the two last rows have the same number between them as well as the two first rows between them even though $0 is not the same.

Comment: @PercevalVellosilloGonzalez In your example `awk` (with wrong syntax) you make no mentioning of "chemical_modifation" or "deletion_inframe". I understand that you want a counter which depends on fields, which again depend on the content of `$3`. However, your example already shows 4 different fields but your code only has 2 examples. This is a bit unclear. Could you please update your question.

Comment: In fact @kvantour. I have written the code in order to explain a summary that I would like to do. When I'm trying to parse it I include all names registered into 3rd column along the file. Now replace the code

Comment: I have updated my answer ... maybe this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'\t' '!a[$3]++{c++} {print c FS $0}' file
```

or the golfed version

```
$ awk '{print (!a[$3]++?++c:c)"\t"$0}' file
```

further

```
$ awk '$0=(!a[$3]++?++c:c)"\t"$0' file
```

Comment: A common idiom is to maintain an otherwise unused count of the occurrences of `$3`: `'!a[$3]++ {c++;} {print c FS $0}'`. Then you can check if `$3` has been seen before *and* record its existence in one step.

Comment: Note that "column 3" in the input is not always `$3`: `/^[^[:blank:]]/ {val=$3} /^[[:blank:]]' {val=$2}` or perhaps something with `substr()`

Comment: yeah, only the first one with explicit `FS` will work for missing fields (tabs are assumed to be in place)

Comment: Thanks @karafka. Nevertheless, your script if I'm right numbered the file based on 3rd column only. But I would like is numbered based on a set of columns that are variable depends on the contents of 3rd column. In fact there are empty fields but are interpreted as blank fields so are included. In this way 3rd column are always "frameshift_variant" or "inframe_deletion" and so on

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question a bit, I believe you want to do something like this :

```
awk -F '\t' '($3=="frameshift_variant") {
                key=$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6
                if !(key in a01) { a01[key]=++c }
                print a01[key] OFS $0
                next
              }
              ($3=="inframe_deletion") {                   
                key=$2" "$3" "$4" "$7
                if !(key in a02) { a02[key]=++c }
                print a02[key] OFS $0
                next
              }
              ($3=="<foo>"} {
                 key=<bar>
                 if !(key in axx) { axx[key]=++c }
                 print axx[key] OFS $0
                 next
              }' file
```

So all you actually need is to build keygen function and then you can do

```
awk -F '\t' 'function keygen() { 
                if      ($3 == "frameshift_variant")    return $2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6
                else if ($3 == "inframe_deletion")      return $2" "$3" "$4" "$7
                else if ($3 == "chemical-modification") return $2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6
                else if ($3 == "deletion_inframe")      return $2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6
             }
             { key = keygen()
               if !(key in a) {a[key]=++c}
               print a[key] OFS $0
             }' file
```

Comment: I think is that I want but when run there are syntax errors due to the "!" symbol but I don't know exactly why. However, I think your script is what I want to do with the file. Nevertheless I'm try only with your script above but not yet with the keygen function. Thanks anyway for helping and provide the scripts since is really very useful for me